# Printing Json data as Html Table

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using PageMethod to retrieve Table data in Json format using the following C# Code

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetJson2()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
    JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw);

    try
    {
        string connstr = "server=localhost;user=root;database=cm_users;port=3306;password=root";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstr);
        conn.Open();
        string sql = "select * from users";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {

            int fieldcount = reader.FieldCount; // count how many columns are in the row
            object[] values = new object[fieldcount]; // storage for column values
            reader.GetValues(values); // extract the values in each column

            jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();
            for (int index = 0; index < fieldcount; index++)
            { // iterate through all columns

                jsonWriter.WritePropertyName(reader.GetName(index)); // column name
                jsonWriter.WriteValue(values[index]); // value in column

            }
            jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();
        }
        reader.Close();

    }
    catch (MySqlException mySqlException)
    { // exception
        return mySqlException + "error";
    }

    // END of method
    // the above method returns sb and another uses it to return as HTTP Response...
    string jsonString = sb.ToString();
    return jsonString; ;
}
```

Now I am Catching the out put of the method into an html Page using an Java Scipt

Using Ajax JavaScript I am consuming the returned string which is in Json format.

```
function getUsers() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://{address}:8078/Default.aspx/GetJson2",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success:  function (msg) {
            $("#Result").text(msg.d);
            var myTable1 = ''; 
            myTable1 += '<table id="myTable1" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 border=1>';
            myTable1 += "<tr><td><b>ID</b></td><td><b>UserName</b></td><td><b>Password</b></td><td><b>Email</b></td></tr>";


            $.each(msg, function(i,v){
                alert(i + v);

                myTable1 += "<tr><td>" + v.id + "</td><td>" + v.username + "</td><td>" + v.password + "</td><td>" + v.Email + "</td></tr>"; 
            });

            $("#user_tb1").html(myTable1) ;
        },
        error:    function () {
            alert("error");
        } 

    });
};
```

I am getting Json string as

{"id":1,"username":"karthik","password":"karthik","Email":"karthikdheeraj@gmail.com"}{"id":2,"username":"Lohith","password":"Lohith","Email":"lohith@cnonymn.com"}

and Html as

A table structure in which each cell is filled with "undefined"

What might be the Issue in the above code.

Comment: The Java Script for it is

Comment: And what is a question here?

Comment: Java Script is sliced above please find the script between 2 code blocks

Comment: There is probably some wrong with your JSON.  Is it missing commas?  I would map your database result to an object and use http://json.codeplex.com/ to serialize to JSON.

Comment: Your json is not valid. It should be `[{...},{....}]`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the json being retrieved from the server is incorrect, it's not an array of objects.

The correct format should be:

```
[
{"id":1,"username":"karthik","password":"karthik","Email":"karthikdheeraj@gmail.com"},
{"id":2,"username":"Lohith","password":"Lohith","Email":"lohith@cnonymn.com"}
]
```

Here's a [plnkr showing your table filling code](http://plnkr.co/edit/cWligJ8qRGf3a965ZMc2?p=preview) working with correctly formatted data

Comment: sorry bud, didn't copy ur answer. I too was working on it as well.

Comment: @KarthikDheeraj if it answered your question, upvote it and accept it. Welcome to SO.

Comment: The C# Method is giving such JSON String
What Is the Correct C# code to generate JSON String From DataBase using DataReaders?

Comment: did you see @Dylan's expanded answer, he shows an example of using the jsonwriter to create an array.  however, it looks complicated. I suggest looking into using JSON.net (http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) or ServiceStack's json serializer (http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=344)

Comment: my answer is just 2 lines of code added to what he already has.
a call to .WriteStartArray() and .WriteEndArray(). JSon.net may be a better way to go with the whole thing though, I was just suggesting a fix to the problem that I saw.

Comment: i am suggesting that the jsonwtextriter is overblown for simple deserialization of a type.

Answer (score 1):

There's something up with the JSON that you are getting back. The proper format needs to be:

```
var json = [{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "karthik",
    "password": "karthik",
    "Email": "karthikdheeraj@gmail.com"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "username": "Lohith",
    "password": "Lohith",
    "Email": "lohith@cnonymn.com"
}];
```

Below is a fiddle I created showing that the loop now alerts the username properly.
http://jsfiddle.net/77YBq/

**After more investigation:** 
To continue to drill into this issue I believe the root of your JSON problem "if the documentation is correct" [JsonWriter Documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter.htm)

I beleive your server code needs to have

```
    jsonWriter.WriteStartArray(); // Starts Json Array notation;

    // This is your existing code
    //================================================================================
    while (reader.Read())
    {

        int fieldcount = reader.FieldCount; // count how many columns are in the row
        object[] values = new object[fieldcount]; // storage for column values
        reader.GetValues(values); // extract the values in each column

        jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();
        for (int index = 0; index < fieldcount; index++)
        { // iterate through all columns

            jsonWriter.WritePropertyName(reader.GetName(index)); // column name
            jsonWriter.WriteValue(values[index]); // value in column

        }
        jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();
    }
    reader.Close();
    //================================================================================
    // End of your existing code

    jsonWriter.WriteEndArray();  // Ends Json Array notation;
```

Answer (score 1):

The JsonTextWriter is not intended to be used in the way you are using it.

You should take advantage of a serialization library so that you aren't writing code to serialize JSON.

Here is a solution that uses JSON.NET.

Include the package at http://json.codeplex.com/ in your solution.

Add this using statement to your file:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Add a class to map your records to.

```
public class User{
   ... properties here

}



[WebMethod]
public static string GetJson2()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
    JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw);
    var users = new List<User>();
    try
    {
        string connstr = "server=localhost;user=root;database=cm_users;port=3306;password=root";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstr);
        conn.Open();
        string sql = "select * from users";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {

            int fieldcount = reader.FieldCount; // count how many columns are in the row
            object[] values = new object[fieldcount]; // storage for column values
            reader.GetValues(values); // extract the values in each column

            users.add(new User { id = reader["id"], username = reader["username"] ..});
        }
        reader.Close();

    }
    catch (MySqlException mySqlException)
    { // exception
        return mySqlException + "error";
    }

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(users);
}
```

You should also consider naming your id, username etc as Id, Username etc so that you are following the correct naming conventions.

Comment: I am writing c# method in default.aspx.cs under                public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetJson()                          {// stmts }....} and I am calling this method form ajax using url like hostaddress:port:default.aspx/getJson.....

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1654695.aspx/1 That is almost exactly what you are trying to do.  Just replace the object properties with yours and rename it users.  Swap out the SqlDataReader for the MySqlDataReader.  After you have a list of objects you should just be able to call JsonConvert.SerializeObject(users).  I added the using statement to include JSON.NET after you have added the reference to your project.